# Could not set content type to application/javascript while returning jsonp from node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsonp, content-type

One quick question:

The following code is returning jsonp with json content from a file as expected, but the content-type of the response is text/javascript. How can I convert it to application/javascript?

I tried adding header prior to res.jsonp, but there were some problems.

```
var express = require("express");
var fs = require("fs");

var server = express();
server.set("jsonp callback", true);
server.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.sendfile(__dirname+'/index.html');
});
server.get("/jsonp", function(req, res) {
    fs.readFile( __dirname + '/test.json', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            throw err; 
        }
        console.log(data.toString());
        res.jsonp(JSON.parse(data.toString()));
    });
});
server.listen('8000');
```

Thanks for help!

Github repo: https://github.com/james-singh/JSONP-Tester/blob/master/app.js

Comment: 'text/javascript' is the right content-type for a jsonp response, why do you want to set it to 'application/javascript'

Comment: not very sure. my server throws jsonp content with text/javascript content type that my client side application built on angularjs is not able to consume using $resources. I am able to read the response with $ajax though, but I need to be able to consume it using $resources.

Comment: could you post the angularjs code in the question:)

Comment: $resources consumes a json response, alter your server code to: "res.send(JSON.parse(data.toString()));", it should work

Comment: if you want to send a jsonp request in angularjs, try this: function jsonp_callback(data) {console.log(data);}
$http.jsonp("http://localhost:8080/jsonp?callback=jsonp_callback");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'text/javascript' is the right content-type for a jsonp response.

if you want to send a jsonp request in angularjs, try this:

```
function jsonp_callback(data) {
    console.log(data);
} 
$http.jsonp("http://localhost:8080/jsonp?callback=jsonp_callback");
```

Comment: yes, it later worked with text/javascript when called using $http